# Single source sound waves and beating

Tags: acoustics, interference

Suppose the human auditory system could perceive sound waves of 1 Hz.  Also suppose that a single source generated waves of such frequency.  Would these waves sound as though they beat?  I ask because it seems to me that if two waves can interfere to produce a wave of the same form as that generated by a single source then both waves should sound the same.

Answer (score 1):

**A single source generating a 1 Hz wave cannot beat.**
[Beating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)) occurs because of the interference of two waves at very similar frequencies.

For example, if you have a 46 Hz and a 40 Hz wave, they would produce an audible beat with frequency 
$$f_{beat} = f_1 - f_2 = 6 Hz$$

You say:

> it seems to me that if two waves can interfere to produce a wave of the same form as that generated by a single source then both waves should sound the same.

I've set up the following image so that you can see what happens to the amplitude of wave 1 (red), wave 2 (blue) and their superimposition (green) over the course of one second.  I hope it's apparent that *the [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves)) of the waveform* has six oscillations. That's the $6 \ Hz$ tone that is audible.

[image: beating demonstration]

A constant single-frequency source by itself has no way of producing this type of envelope.